# Count + 1 process builder / wf

Tags: process-builder, administration

Is it possible to use pb/wf for this case: or apex trigger ?

Once the record is created I need to display like this is the first record created(number field = 1) then 2nd record created = 2 , 3rd = 3, etc to itself..

Comment: Have you considered using a native Auto Number field?

Comment: @DavidReed Yes but it needs to be reset for every parent record.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to keep the counter in a hidden parent field since the numbers should start new for every parent.

The PB Flow should listen on the new creation of a child record and assign the number based on the parent record info +1.

[image]

Then you should have a update action that sets the field on the parent by the same formula:

[image]

Comment: Mendez Thanks man, now I'm thinking if I can make it like 01 , 02 , 03 , 04 .... 11, 12 ,13, 14. w/out using formula concatenate()

Comment: The counter should still be a numeric value so you can increase it easily. But of course you can choose any formula you want to populate the child record identifier field. That depends what should be the format of this field. Mark the answer as accepted if this helped you.